# How catch event from <input type="date"> by wicket ajax behaviors?

Tags: java, wicket

I have an input field:

```
<input type="date" wicket:id="date">
```

and try catch change event in `js` like that:

```js
let dateInput = document.querySelector('input[type=date]');
dateInput.onchange = log;


function log() {
   console.log(this + " - " +event+": " + this.value);
}
```

But in java some behaviour like:

```java
DateTextField dateField = new DateTextField("dateField");
dateField.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Or

```java
DateTextField dateField = new DateTextField("dateField");
dateField.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
});
```

Or

```java
DateTextField dateField = new DateTextField("dateField");
dateField.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
});
```

can't catch this event.

DateTextField is org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.DateTextField;

Comment: Hi, could you show some more Java code you use to bind Ajax behavior to Wicket component? behaviors code looks fine.

Comment: Which version of Wicket do you use?

Comment: @martin-g , 8.6.1

Comment: @AndreaDelBene , added a component that I use in java code.
This is all that is on the page.

Comment: @AndreaDelBene , i have a new problem, while i update my dateField at java i catch event 2 times, and for the first time the correct value is set in the model, but in 2nd time null value set in the model.
Why i have 2 time update event? Should I make a separate question on this topic? Cant find some information about this theme

Comment: Hi, I think it's better if you create a separate question, just to be more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution - need correct date pattern , pattern at input must match pattern at java Date.
This is work :

```java
DateTextField dateField= new DateTextField("dateField", Model.of(new Date()),"yyyy-MM-dd");
dateField.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
});
```